# MVC/PDO : What should and shouldn't be in a model class?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, pdo

So I'm trying to build an application following the MVC pattern in PHP.

I'm having trouble building my model class. Here's a quick summary of what I have done so far with the model :

```
<?php

class Database {


    private $_db;
    private $_host;
    private $_dbname;
    private $_user;

    public function __construct($host, $dbname, $user, $password = '') {

        if (empty($host) OR empty($dbname) OR empty($user)) {
            return false;
        }
        $this->_db = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $host . ';dbname=' . $dbname, $user, $password);
        $this->_host = $host;
        $this->_dbname = $dbname;
        $this->_user = $user;

    }

    // Checks if a given table already exists
    public function tableExists($table) {...}


}
```

So the question is : when I want to use the database with some controllers, for example, when I want to select all the messages sent by a specific user, should I create a method called `select()` in the `Database` class or should I write the SQL query (using a prepared statement) inside the controller's class ?

I'm really new to the MVC pattern, so I don't know what the extent of my model class should be.

I hope someone has the answer for me !

Comment: All your business logic (queries especially) should ideally go in the model. Have a read of this if you like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_logic

Comment: I had a look at that and it's very interesting. Thank you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It really depend how you write your code. You can write all the 'abstractions' in your current Database class. So something like

```
public function select($table)
{
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM $table"
  //run and execute
}
```

In some popular frameworks, each table on database has it own model class, which using this database class.

```
class User extends Database {
 ..
}
```

And the controller will be using which model class needed,

```
class Home extends Controller {

function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
}

function index() {
    $this->load->model('user');
 }
}
```

Even if you haven't use any framework, it good to see how frameworks implements this mvc to help you get started [Codigniter model](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/models.html)

*This tutorial will help you for sure [Codecourse MVC](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLfdtiltiRHWGXVHXX09fxXDi-DqInchFD)

Answer (score 2):

> when I want to select all the messages sent
>   by a specific user, should I create a method called select() in the
>   Database class or should I write the SQL query (using a prepared
>   statement) inside the controller's class ?

Put the method and any SQL query in the Model class, `Database` in this case.  This `select()` method will likely take some parameter that will be passed on to it from the controller to be used in the query, like the user-id in this example.

Controllers are only for handling input, converting that input into commands to be processed by the Model and/or View.  They should not themselves run any business logic like SQL queries.

Comment: But why would the view need to process any data if the controller already does it ?

Comment: The view doesn't "process" data, it just displays it.  The controller takes user input and hands it off to the model, the model operates on it and hands it to the view, and the view displays it.